# Guide to Create a Compiler using Pascal

Tags: pascal

Can anyone tell me a book, videos, website, or journals that show a complete guide to create a compiler using pascal. Im confuse when looking for the Semantic Analyzer, intermediate code, to optimizing code

Comment: I'm afraid asking for those sorts of recommendattions is off-topic here at SO.  You might try asking here: https://en.delphipraxis.net/  Also, this book is well worth a look:  http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920002.do

Comment: Thank u so much I'll take a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

"Let's Build a Compiler" by Jack Crenshaw